# Show that $f(A)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, let $f: \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable, and suppose that $det(D_xf) \neq 0$ for all $x$ Show that $f(A)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

### My Attempt:

Given that the determinant of the differential for all $x$ does not equal $0$ and that $f$ is continuously differentiable (class $C^ \infty),$ we can use the inverse function theorem for all $x\in A$.

Now we know that there exists open sets $U,V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a function $f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with some conditions.

How do I prove this using the inverse function theorem?

Comment: HINT: The inverse function theorem tells you that there is an neighborhood $U_x$ for each $x \in A$ such that $f(U_x)$ is open.

Comment: and $f(U_x)\in V_x$? $f:U_x \rightarrow V_x$.There also exists an inverse function, say $g:V_x \rightarrow U_x$?  $f$ and $g$ are inverses of each other (If that even helps)

Comment: Right, but that's not important for showing that $f(A)$ is open.

Comment: Maybe we can somehow show that $f(A)= \cup V_x$? (Since the Union of open sets are open?)

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea.

Comment: Doesn't that hold just by construction? I can't seem to find the words to put together